OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "Logging" returned message "The parameter is incorrect"
Our problem:

We have multiple clients, each with their own database.
We are logging changes from certain tables to a central database called Central.
The logging process requires SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE permissions.
No client should be able to view the data from another client.
Client databases and Central are on the same Azure MI (Managed Instance).

Our current solution

Create a SQL login called Logging_User.
Create a user within the Central database based on logging_User and give it permission to read/write to the logging tables.
Create a linked server Logging that connects to the local MI and uses Logging_User for all connections.
In the client databases, a trigger exists for each of the tables being logged.
The triggers reference the linked server to do the inserts/queries in the logging tables. i.e. INSERT INTO Logging.Central.dbo.Log_Table

The problem
While this works great from SSMS when we run the application we get the following error:

Error: -2147217900. OLE DB provider "MSSQLDBSQL" for linked server
"Logging" returned message "The parameter is incorrect.".

From what research I've done it appears this is a distributed transaction error, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet. This is made harder by the fact that it's a Managed Instance and the linked server connects to the local instance. Not a common solution I realize.
Edit:
Here are the linked server properties:

Also, the security is "Be made using this security context" using the user mentioned above.

I hate triggers - any way you could use Change Tracking or CDC and bring the changes over via a batch process every couple minutes?  You wouldn't have up-to-the-second data in your Central database, but you wouldn't have to bother with triggers.

I don't mind triggers if they are used correctly, but regardless in this particular case we could have done something differently if we'd been in the design talks early on. At this point it's how do we solve the permissions problem with as few changes as possible. Not to mention the maintenance as we add new clients.

Ok, understood.  I assume for Linked Server security you're using "Be made using this security context" with your Logging_User credentials in there?  What are your Linked Server settings for Data Access, RPC, PRC Out, and Enable Promotion of Distributed Transaction?

@Dave.Gugg Edited and added an image of the settings above. And yes to the security setting being "Be made using this security context".

Not sure if your trigger is calling a PROC or not, does turning RPC and PRC Out = True fix it?  Are you comfortable turning the Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions off?  That would probably depend on your transaction rollback strategy.

The Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions didn't help. It used to be off and I turned it on with no help either way. I don't think there are any SP calls, but maybe RPC and RPC Out work on triggers too? I'll give it a shot.

Might be a code issue - is it using TransactionScope ?  And did you enable Distributed Transaction Coordinator in the Azure portal for your Managed Instance?

@Greg I'm not sure about the code, I don't have access to it so I'll have to ask. Also I'm not finding the DTC in the Azure portal for my MI. I did find the article where they talked about it but they've changed the interface since then and it's not there anymore. Also from this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-transactions-overview?view=azuresql it looks like I don't need to turn anything on since it's all on a MI.

@Dave.Gugg RPC and RPC Out didn't work.

@KennethFisher, in the azure portal for your managed instance, go to Settings -> Distributed Transaction Coordinator. There are three tabs - on tab Basics, there is where you'll fine the setting for "Distributed Transaction Coordinator".  However, it does say, for databases on one managed instance, you should try using "SQL Trust groups".

@Greg It's weird, I can only see the DTC on some of our MIs. I tried turning it on and then got "Transaction context in use by another session.". So now we are trying to create a Trust group. Of course I can't create a trust group for just the one MI so I'm creating it with a random other MI to see if it works anyway. This connection is between 2 DBs on the same instance.
